# What is the best way to master keyboard: Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic?

Tags: technology

I decided to take care of my hands and bought the said keyboard. But I ran into a few problems when using it:

```
I have not yet found a suitable finger layout.
As a consequence, it is making learning to touch type very difficult.
```

The keyboard is very special, and therefore, I am guessing there must be a special solution for it.

Who else has had this problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: Technical support and learning how to use this keyboard is off topic for this site. It may be a good fit for Super User, but please see their **[help center](http://superuser.com/help)** regarding what is on topic there.

Comment: FWIW As you can't type now and are starting from ground-level, I encourage you to explore the DVORAK key layout. It will save you time learning, you'll type faster with less effort. It's based on ergonomics developed AFTER the typewriter.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the older Ergonomic keyboard occasionally (a partner had one).  I found it worked fine with the standard home key finger placement (*asdf jkl;* on an English QWERTY keyboard).  My reaches and strokes were the same as what I learned (on manual and Selectric typewriters) in 1975, though it took a little practice to get comfortable with the hand positions after twenty-some years on flat computer keyboards.

If you need to *learn* touch typing, follow the standard methods; the keys are in standard QWERTY order, including the upper row number/symbol keys, enter, backspace, tab, and cap lock, unless you've loaded a Dvorak or other alternate layout in software.  If you're not working in English on your computer, hopefully you were able to get the Sculpt Ergonomic in your own language character set, and if so, it should support the same home keys and technique as a standard keyboard for your language.